# Django & Heroku | How to log 400 error in detail?

Tags: django, heroku

I have created an app on Heroku and I push my Django app to it.

I monitor the logs using `heroku logs --tail` to see them in real time.

How to display 400 error log in detail at such a production environment (when `DEBUG=false`)?

I know `debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)`method and use it for logging 400 errors by overriding handler500 
 (ex. `handler500=my_custom_exception_logger.server_error`).

But it seems there is no `technical_400_response` method.

I'm using

```
Django 1.11.5
Python 3.6.1
whitenoise 3.3.0
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings myapp.wsgi --log-file -
```

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,   
    'formatters': { 
        'all': {    
            'format': '\t'.join([
                "[%(levelname)s]",
                "asctime:%(asctime)s",
                "module:%(module)s",
                "message:%(message)s",
                "process:%(process)d",
                "thread:%(thread)d",
            ])
        },
    },
    'handlers': {  
        'file': {  
            'level': 'DEBUG',  
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',  
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django.log'),  
            'formatter': 'all',  
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'all'
        },
    },
    'loggers': { 
        'command': {  
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],  
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the best way to debug 400 error for me was to use chrome developer console.

#### django, api view

```
if item.is_valid():
    // do some thing...
else:
    return Response(item.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

#### client side, ajax

```
var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 )
    {
      if( this.response )
      {
        var res = this.response;
        console.log(this.response);
        // do something...
      }
    }
  }
  ...
```

Then tested POST request to my django server, responseText told me why it failed.